# How to restrict given method/class use in current code

Tags: c#, deprecated, obsolete

In C#, `[Obsolete]` can be used for the 'code author' to mark code obsolete.

However, is there a method for the **'code user'** to mark that a method/class is restricted in his/her code?

In C++ (Visual C++), we have `#pragma deprecated`to archive this purpose, more or less. Is there a counterpart in C#?

For example,

.Net provides `Marshal.SizeOf()` method in `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` class. I do not want to use `Marshal.SizeOf()` in my code, but do need some other methods in `Marshal` class. How can I apply the policy in code other than check the code by my eyes... (Use proxy class/etc. is too heavy for this purpose.)

In Visual C++, `#pragma deprecated` has limited function for this purpose.

Comment: Is it about restricting class/method in your own dll/library? If so try internal modifier. I don't think we can limit class to particular code unless we inspect the call stack programatically and throw exception if its not from our code.

Comment: I want to restrict the usage of System/3rd library, not my code. In other words, I want to restrict `imports` not `exports`

Comment: If we cannot restrict the usage in code directly, even a compiler extension solution (LINT ect.) is acceptable. If not to heavy, I may create it by myself. I have expect such function in C++ for long time. Now in C#, again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, are you trying to get the compiler to issue an error if a deprecated method is used?

If so simply use the `[Obsolete(String, bool)]` version ([MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/961hff5d.aspx)) and set the `bool` parameter to `true` and the compiler will issue an error for usages of that method